# Json in array Javascript and Ajax

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, laravel

I write code in JS (Ajax):

```
function getSportIdAndLeagueId() {

    var action = 'http://localhost:8012/football/football/public/admin/ajax/';
    var teamId = document.getElementById('team_a_id').value;

    var question = "";
    question = new XMLHttpRequest();

    question.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if ( question.readyState == 4 && question.status == 200 ) {
                // document.getElementById('sport_id').innerHTML = question.responseText;
                var allRecord = question.responseText;
                var sport_id = "";
                var league_id = "";

                for (var i = 0; i < allRecord.length; i++) {
                    sport_id = sport_id + allRecord[i];
                    league_id = league_id + allRecord[i];        
                }

                document.getElementById('sport_id').innerHTML = sport_id;
                document.getElementById('league_id').innerHTML = league_id;
        } else {

            document.getElementById('sport_id').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + question.statusText + ' code: ' + question.status + ' readyState: ' + question.readyState;

        }

    }

    question.open("get", action + teamId, true);
    question.send();

}
```

Ajax returned me records in JSON in Array, look like this:

```
sport_id:
[{"id":110,"sport_id":1,"league_id":32}]
league_id:
[{"id":110,"sport_id":1,"league_id":32}]
```

I can't get only number of `sport_id` and `league_id`. I trying add code from this theme [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204983/iterate-and-map-json-in-array-using-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top):

```
if(sport_id[i]._type[0]=='sport_id'){
    currentObj = pushNew(sport_id[i].nodeValue);
}
```

But I have returned Error:

> statusText: OK Status: 200 readyState: 3

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your desired output

```
question.responseType = 'jsonp';

  for (x in sport_id) {
        document.getElementById("sport_id").innerHTML += sport_id[x] + " ";
    }

 for (x in league_id) {
        document.getElementById("league_id").innerHTML += league_id[x] + " ";
    }
```

Comment: Stil I have this same error: statusText: OK Status: 200 readyState: 3

Comment: I have updated code. And I think your data format is not standard, means JSONP